# Cordova inappbrowser passing cookies parameter to website page for login authentication purpose

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic3

We have the requirement to handle and pass the **JSESSIONID** into webpage to achieve the auto login.

We are developing the ionic based hybrid mobile app and we have the option to use inApp browser to open the PWA app page.
the requirement is who are logged user, the user should not enter the credentials to login inApp browser page with help of **JSESSIONID** token passing to achieve this solution.

The developed page **Liferary** portal page and mobile app developed ionic based application.

how do we pass the **JSESSIONID** id while using inApp browser page link. we do not have any idea about, how do we pass the **JSESSIONID** value along with webpage.

I saw the sample in CURL pages open but how de we use similar approach or any other best solution ionic mobile app.

https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360036708571-Making-Authenticated-Requests#using-cookie-authentication-or-doing-a-request-from-the-portal

how to pass **JSESSIONID** and headers in inApp browser in ionic or cordova based application. please help us and give you inputs

Comment: Did you try to set the cookie using executeScript?

Comment: can you please share the samples docs..

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the cookies using the executeScript as mentioned below.
Also, you can set the browser to be hidden so the user won't feel that the login page was opened.

```
this.inAppBrowserInstance = this.inAppBrowser.create(URL, '_blank');    
this.inAppBrowserInstance.on('beforeload')
      .subscribe(event => {
        this.inAppBrowserInstance.executeScript({ code: `document.cookie = "JSESSIONID=cookievalue"` }).then()
```

Please note the I didn't test the code on a device

Comment: we are using typescript and above the code will support? i could see document property.. sometime the typescript will not take this..

Comment: The document property is the code you want to execute on the Webview. It is a string anyway, so TS won't complain (It won't complain actually even if it was used in TS)

Comment: inAppBrowserInstance.executeScript({ code: 'document.cookie = "JSESSIONID=" '+response.JSESSIONID }).then(res => { }).    i am parsing cookies value is correct. please confirm

Comment: this.inAppBrowserInstance.on('beforeload')
      .subscribe(event => {
        this.inAppBrowserInstance.executeScript({ code: `document.cookie = "JSESSIONID=cookievalue"` }).then() -- the code not execute and the block not at all calling. please help us

Comment: Try to call `alert` to make sure it is executing the block with correct value `"alert(document.cookie='JSESSIONID="+cookievalue+"')"`

Comment: thanks lot, will try and let you know if any success or failure

Comment: Hi, we tested, not at all the alert and on subscribe event not working. please help us

Comment: Hi, we tested, not at all the alert and on subscribe event not working. please help us

Comment: What is your `@ionic-native/in-app-browser` version? Try to use it with `_blank` target

Comment: Hi, our @ionic-native/in-app-browser version3.2.0 and we are using _system properties . please suggest and we are waiting for your valuable inputs

Comment: There was a bug with before load event and it was fixed in 5.18.0. Please note that your version is very old, you need to update it. If you don't want to update for some reason, you can follow `mread1208` fix at the end of the thread here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/2819

Comment: We tried above one sample and the cookie setting in browser but we need to refresh the page then only the cookie take. ideally the two jsession id generating the web page. how do we refresh the page at least one time. if we use window.location.reload(), the entire mobile app refresh to load again and again. please suggest

Comment: we did document.location.reload in android working fine but the ios page keep loading and loading again. can you please help us

Comment: Please add the code that sets the cookies. Regarding the reload, please open another issue as it is not related for this topic.

Comment: hi , i tried cookies setup inApp browser but if i am close the page and again open the inApp sometime the login not happen. is it possible to clear the cookies inApp browser page ? please help us

Comment: You need to check if you are using any of these options when openning the Webview, then it will clear the cache / data / session:  `cleardata: 'yes'`, `clearcache: 'yes'` or `clearsessioncache: 'yes'`

Comment: Hi We tried to added the parameter but jsession is not clear at browser side, can you please help us.

Comment: Can you create a github repo so we can take a look at the code?

Comment: you wont be able to access the cookie, if your cookie is HttpOnly